# CSS Elements Responding to :hover

Tags: html, css, hover, resize, element

I have been working on a little project that I am needing some help with. I'm new to HTML and CSS and have been practicing with a little snippet.

```
 <div class="mysection">
    <div class="holdit"><a href=# class="apd"><span></span></a><br />Right</div>
    <div class="holdit"><a href=# class="norm"><span></span></a><br />Left</div>
 </div>
```

I want to make it so that when apd is hovered, both apd and norm (span specifically) will change in equal size (let's say from 60px to 50px).

When apd is hovered, I want both norm and apd to shrink even smaller (from 60px to 30px).

If you were to swing your cursor back and forth between the two, the element sizes will adjust based on which is hovered. If none are hovered, they will go back to their non-hovered size (60px). I feel like this should be very simple, however, despite my best efforts, I haven't been able to get the elements to work as desired. Here is the CSS:

```
     a.apd:hover span { background-color:#000; width: 50px; height: 50px;  } 
     .mysection:hover a.norm span { background-color:#000; width: 30px; height: 30px;  }
     a.norm:hover a.apd span { background-color:#000; width: 30px; height: 30px;  }
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there's nothing else inside the parent `div.mysection` you want to avoid hovering, you can select both elements by putting the `:hover` state on the parent of both elements.

```css
.mysection span
{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
}

.mysection:hover span
{
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="mysection">
    <div class="holdit"><a href=# class="apd"><span></span></a><br />Right</div>
    <div class="holdit"><a href=# class="norm"><span></span></a><br />Left</div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<head>
  <style>
    .mysection:hover .holdit{
    
      background-color:orange;
      padding-left:10%;
    }
     .mysection:hover .holdit{
      background-color:orange;
      
      padding-left:10%;
    }
    .apd{
      background-color:red;
      border-radius:5%;
      width:100%;
    }
    .norm{
      background-color:green;
      border-radius:5%;
      width:100%;
    }
    .mysection{
      background-color:blue;
      width:50%;
    }
    .holdit{
      width:100%;
      border-radius:25px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div style="width:100%;background-color:purple">
  <div class="mysection">
      <div class="holdit"><a href=# class="apd"><span></span><br />Right</a></div>
      <div class="holdit"><a href=# class="norm"><span></span><br />Left</a></div>
   </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want. In CSS, you can hover the div to scale every element but it won't be accurate because if the div is big, I can over my mouse anywhere out of your two elements and they will get scaled. Check the snippet.

With JavaScript, you can control them. If you want code improvement, I will suggest you create a class for both.

```js
 var apd = document.getElementsByClassName("apd")[0]
            var norm = document.getElementsByClassName("norm")[0]
    
            apd.addEventListener("mouseover", function( event ) {
                norm.style.width="60px";
                norm.style.height="60px";
                apd.style.width="60px";
                apd.style.height="60px";
            }, false)
                    
            norm.addEventListener("mouseover", function( event ) {
                norm.style.width="60px";
                norm.style.height="60px";
                apd.style.width="60px";
                apd.style.height="60px";
            }, false)
    
            apd.addEventListener("mouseout", function( event ) {
                norm.style.width="50px";
                norm.style.height="50px";
                apd.style.width="50px";
                apd.style.height="50px";
            }, false)
    
            norm.addEventListener("mouseout", function( event ) {
                norm.style.width="50px";
                norm.style.height="50px";
                apd.style.width="50px";
                apd.style.height="50px";
            }, false)
```

```css
.mysection{
                outline: 2px dashed blue;
            }
    
            .mysection a
            {
                width: 50px;
                height: 50px;
                background: red;
                display: inline-block;
                outline: 2px dashed green;
            }
```

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="mysection">
            <div><a href=# class="apd"><span></span></a><br/>Right</div>
            <div><a href=# class="norm"><span></span></a><br/>Left</div>
        </div>  
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was trying to figure out. Thank you